# Comparing 3 columns of two sheets ,if found matching copying value of 4th column of first sheet to second

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare 3 columns in two sheets in a workbook and if all 3 columns are matching then copying the value of first sheet(Column G) to Column P of the second sheet.
I am trying to use the below code but it does not seem to work.(Returns blank)

```
Sub CopyCells()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim j As Long, i As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Set sh1 = Worksheets("EOD")
    Set sh2 = Worksheets("Consolidated")

    lastrow1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow1
        For j = 2 To lastrow2
            If sh1.Cells(i, "A").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "B").Value And _
                sh1.Cells(i, "B").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "C").Value And _
                sh1.Cells(i, "C").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "D").Value Then
                sh1.Cells(i, "G").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "P").Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it seems like the way you are copying the value of the first sheet to the second sheet on column P is the wrong way around, should read as: sh2.cells(j, "P").value = sh1.cells(i, "G").value

Comment: Hi ,Thanks Xabier.I tried that.Still getting blanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following code and it does as you wanted:

```
Sub CopyCells()
LastRow1 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow1
    For j = 2 To LastRow2
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value = Sheet2.Cells(j, "B").Value Then
            If Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = Sheet2.Cells(j, "C").Value Then
                If Sheet1.Cells(i, "C").Value = Sheet2.Cells(j, "D").Value Then
                    Sheet2.Cells(j, "P").Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, "G").Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this.Unfortunately, It still seems to give me blank. result

Comment: Could it be that you have blank data on column G of Sheet1? I have tested this and works as you requested... If you want me to have a look at this, please include some sample data on your question, so that I have a better overview of your issues...